# how to prefer static page if it exists over wordpress page

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, apache

I've created a custom post type for my landing pages, which each sit at `www.mydomain.com/lp/<page-name>/`

I want to keep those custom posts there, so they show up with proper featured images and excerpts on archive and search pages. However, in some cases, if someone goes to a specific page, I want it to load a static page, and associated style sheets and scripts from the directory where the static page is.

So, imagine the following URI hierarchy:

```
www.mysite.com/lp/page-a/
                 /page-b/   // this page exists in WP for search/archive purposes
                 /page-c/
```

The above pages all exist in WordPress and work fine. Now, there could be a directory structure on the server like

```
/vhost/mysite/www/wp-content
                 /wp-includes
                 /foo/page-b.html
                     /page-b.css
                     /public/page-b.js
```

If someone navigates to `/lp/page-x/`, if `page-x.html` exists in `/foo`, I want it to load that, and I want relative references internal to `page-x.html` (e.g., `<script id="page-x-js" src="./public/page-x.js" defer></script>`) to pull from that directory path. But if they go to `www.mysite.com/lp/page-a/` and `/vhost/mysite/www/foo/page-a.html` doesn't exist, I want WordPress to load the normal, internal custom post.

The directory structure doesn't really matter — I have full control over the server. And while I assume this is some `.htaccess` magic, I'm running Apache and can make changes to the config, or I could even add code to my plugin that creates the custom pages.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: "If someone navigates to `/page-x/`" - Presumably you mean `/lp/page-x/`? Presumably `<script id="page-x-js" src="./public/page-x.js" defer></script>` does not exist in the WordPress generated page?

Comment: Yes, on both counts. I meant `/lp/page-x/`, and will update it in the post. Said script will not exist in the generated page, though other relative paths which don't start with `.` may exist in both.

Comment: Actually, thinking through it some more, probably other relative paths won't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Sending the request to `/foo/page-x.html` if it exists.
2. Overriding the relative URL-paths to your static resources.

Normally, when rewriting the URL in this way (to different path depths) you should *not* be using relative URL-paths to your static resources, since the *browser* naturally resolves this relative to the URL-path displayed in the browser (this is not a file-path). However, if we know what URL-path is being requested and what file-path it should correspond to (as we appear to know in this case) then we can potentially override/correct this with additional rewrite(s) in `.htaccess`. If the same relative URL-path is used from different URLs then this becomes increasingly difficult to resolve as you would need to hardcode each possibility. Normally you should be using root-relative (or absolute) URL-paths to static resources to avoid this conflict/ambiguity.

The "problem" with the relative URL-path is that when requesting `/lp/<page-name>/`, a relative URL-path of the form `./public/page-x.js` is resolved as `/lp/<page-name>/public/page-x.js` by the browser. So we need to rewrite this to `/foo/public/page-x.js`.

These rules need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file located at `/vhost/mysite/www/.htaccess` (which I assume is the *document root*). Importantly, this needs to go *before* the WordPress code block (ie. before `# BEGIN WordPress`).

```
# 1. Rewrite "/lp/<page-name>/" to "/foo/<page-name>.html" if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/foo/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^lp/([\w-]+)/$ /foo/$1.html [L]

# 2. Rewrite "relative" static resources
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/foo/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^lp/[\w-]+/([\w/-]+\.\w{2,5})$ /foo/$1 [L]
```

As denoted by the subpattern `[\w-]+`, I'm assuming `<page-name>` can consist of just the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen).

**UPDATE:** I've removed `public/` from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and included a slash (`/`) in the character class so to match *any* relative URL-path. It is advisable to keep the `\.\w{2,5}` part in order to avoid matching "too much". We only want to match actual file requests (that contain a file extension), not literally *anything*.

Comment: Awesome! I had to fiddle a little bit to get it to work: the second RewriteCond needs to check in the `foo` dir: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/foo/$1 -f`. And the rewrite rule to generate the `$1` should match anything (so it gets the `/foo/page-b.css`, in addition to the public stuff: `RewriteRule ^lp/[\w-]+/(.*)$ /landing-page/$1 [L]`. I already upvoted, but if you want to make those changes, I'll mark as correct.

Comment: @philolegein Sorry, I missed the `foo` on the `RewriteCond` directive! I've also removed `public/` so that it matches _any_ relative URL-path (need to also add a slash to the character class in that case). Rather than literally matching anything (ie. `(.*)`) it is still advisable to be more restrictive with the regex and match actual files (that contain a file extension). I've updated my answer.